# TSQLConnection will not open on iOS device once deployed to the App Store

Tags: ios, firemonkey, datasnap, delphi-10-seattle, midas-server

After deploying my app to apple Store and testing it with "TestFlight" the app won't open an SQLConnect connection, I get an external exception (434C4E47432B2B00).  But if I deploy the app directly to my devices (iPhone, iPad, simulator) the application works just fine. I am using Delphi Seattle, MIDAS, Datasnap. Don't know if I am missing a setting or a uses before deploying.

I tried adding Datasnap.midas to my uses with no success. Not sure if I should use Midas or Midaslib, if I use Midaslib I get an error when I compile the project.
The same app was published and working fine with Delphi xe6.
Please help!

Comment: Are both the direct deploy and the TestFlight deploy going to the same device? Is this 32-bit or 64-bit? Does the remote server support HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are connecting to an HTTP server that doesn't have SSL enabled. iOS 9 requires that all connections use HTTPS. There is a work around though.

Change your client plist file (Project.plist) Go to the bottom of the file and insert the following text above the last /dict tag:

```
        <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
        <dict>
          <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
        </dict>
```

[More information](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2015/09/24/43917)

Comment: This is sure a good advice, but the connection issue will also happen in the simulator, not only on the app store.

Comment: It may be something different, but I wasn't sure if both were installing to the same device. If the TestFlight is deployed to an iOS 9 device, but a iOS 8 device is used locally then that would explain it.